# php date_create_from_format not working correctly

Tags: php, date

When I use

```
<?php
$mnth=date_format(date_create_from_format('m', '2'), 'F');
echo $mnth;
?>
```

It displays March instead of February. I have similar issues for April,June,September and November. Anyone have Idea about this. Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use '!m' as format. The '!' resets all fields (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, fraction and timezone information) to the Unix Epoch. Without '!' all fields will be set to the current date and time. Today is 31-08-2018 and February, April, June, September and November don't have 31 days.

```
<?php
$mnth = date_format(date_create_from_format('!m', '2'), 'F');
echo $mnth;
?>
```

Comment: yeahh...its working Can you say why my code not working for these months. All except months are working. Only these 30 days month have this problem

Answer (score 0):

When we don't provide date to createFromFormat it will take as today's date by default.
'!' resets all fields (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, fraction and timzone information)

```
$mnth = date_format(date_create_from_format('!m', '2'), 'F');
```